Calculating Gradients in a workflow involving rasterization and image/polygon transformation
I have an odd little problem facing me for my project.
I have a smooth polygon defined by parameters.
I have  convolution transformation, similar to a Gaussian blur. This transformation can only be applied to an image.
Consequently, I need to convert the polygon to an image. I then apply the transformation. This is straightforward.
However, it is important I am able to backpropagate the gradient back to the parameters of the polygon.
I can get the jacobian of the rasterized shape vs the transformed shape. That gives me the derivative with respect to every pixel.
But how on earth do I backpropagate it to the original polygon?

What have you tried? Have you read any literature? A google search for "differentiable rasterization" brings up a lot of promising work on computing gradients of maps from vector graphics to pixel representations.
